# Plotly error cannot change working directory

Tags: r, plotly

I'm using windows 10 and Rstudio and trying to look at the plotly library but I keep getting the error: Error in setwd(dir) : cannot change working directory.

For example:

```
libray(plotly)

plot_ly(
    y = rnorm(50), 
    type = "box", 
    boxpoints = "all", 
    jitter = 0.3,
    pointpos = -1.8
    )
```

> Error in setwd(dir) : cannot change working directory

```
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/me/Documents/R"
```

Any idea how to fix this/why this happens?

Comment: did you tried setwd() to your desire path?

Comment: Hi Dinesh. Yes it doesn't matter to where I set it, I still get that error

Comment: can you send me the path that you tried to set Ex: setwd("c:/Users...........)

Comment: If set it manually like so: setwd("C:/Users/me/Documents/R") it works fine. But I only get the problem when try any plot_ly command. Basically if you run that command that I pasted above, do you get an error?

Comment: plot_ly(y = rnorm(50), type = "box", boxpoints = "all", jitter = 0.3,pointpos = -1.8)
This is the code I executed there is no error

Comment: Hmm perhaps its the version of rstudio or r? Both are the latest... plot(x=rnorm(50),y = rnorm(50), type = "box", boxpoints = "all", jitter = 0.3,pointpos = -1.8) works fine but not plot_ly

Comment: hmmm maybe, my version is RStudio-0.99.489 and R-3.2.3 once try installing this versions(if your versions are these.)

Comment: hmmm mine are the same, (latest versions) so must be something else. really strange don't you think? It happens regardless of what directory I'm in. Why is plotly trying set the wd anyway?

Comment: finally once try to uninstall plot_ly package and set your directory, after setting it, restart your R session and try to install the package and run your code (if u didn't tried this process earlier.....)

Comment: I've tried it and still the same... perhaps I should install it into a different library directory?